# Normalize the variational wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, variational-principle

I am trying to normalize the following variational wave function:
$$\psi(x,\alpha)= |x|^{\alpha} + L^{\alpha}$$

and I'm using this:
$$1= \int_{-L}^{L} |\psi(x,\alpha)|^2 dx$$

Solving the integral gave me:

$$1=2L^{2\alpha + 1} (1 + \frac{1}{2\alpha + 1} + \frac{2}{\alpha + 1})$$

and know I need to solve in order $\alpha$ and I can't do it.

I don't know if my problem is before in some calculation or something else.

Comment: There might be a factor of 2 lost in the last term. Otherwise, it is a transcedental equation that should be solved numerically. It looks however rather strange as a wave function...

Comment: yes, it was missing it

Comment: Why do you think you need to solve for $\alpha$? You've done all the hard stuff you just need to square root it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're simply calculating the normalization of an un-normalized wavefunction.  You need to include some normalization constant, so $\psi(x,\alpha) = C (|x|^\alpha + L^\alpha)$.  If you do that, then you'll find

$$1=|C^2| 2L^{2\alpha + 1} (1 + \frac{1}{2\alpha + 1} + \frac{2}{\alpha + 1})$$

so if you set
$$C = \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2L^{2\alpha + 1} (1 + \frac{1}{2\alpha + 1} + \frac{2}{\alpha + 1})}}$$

then your $\psi$ will be normalized.

Comment: Thx, man! I thought $\alpha$ was the normalization constant|